# Add dynamic string in moodle form help icon

Tags: php, moodle

I am new in Moodle. I have requirement to add dynamic help text in help icon created using $mform->addHelpbutton(); function. But we are not able to do this.

Can anyone tell me any another way to pass the dynamic string in moodles form help icon.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Where does the dynamic text should come from? The database? Should it be calculated at once (current date, some URL)?

Comment: Yes, dynamic text should come from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *addHelpButton()* method has the parameter *$component* that contains the current text to be shown when clicking onto the help icon ([image: Help icon]). This text is read from the *$string* array defined in the language file.

The trick here is that the array element can be built dynamically:-)

Let's make an example:
In your mod_form.php you build your help icon with:

```
$mform->addHelpButton ( 'element_name', 'your_identifier', 'your_help_text' );
```

The text *your_help_text* is read in your language file usually with:

```
$string ['your_help_text_help'] = 'This is my static help text';
```

Here you change this line with:

```
$string ['your_help_text_help'] = get_dynamic_help_string($any_parameter);
```

And then you define your function:

```
function get_dynamic_help_string($any_parameter) {
$text = This is my dynamic help text with the current date: ;
$text .= ' '.date("Y/m/d");
return $text; }
```

Now, any time you refresh the form, the help text will be built dynamically. Of course, you can use any logic here, if you want.

Note: you need here to manage the cache of your plugin in order to always get the newest result of your function. Please, refer to this [link](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Cache_API) for deleting the Moodle cache.